# Creating a Variable of Function from Text using $$

Tags: php

I was thinking today at how all the OOP works.

And i was thinking: Wouldn't be great to check if a method exists using a given text value ?

So, if i have a text function_name_in_text_format, how do i check if the method function_name_in_text_format exists ?

I heard of a solution, something with using $$, but could not find real examples

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php found with http://bit.ly/MXknd7

Comment: [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [is_callable()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) function.

> Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function.
> This can check that a simple variable contains the name of a valid
> function, or that an array contains a properly encoded object and
> function name.

There are also the [function_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) and [method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) functions that can be used as the name indicates.

The method for using $$ is known as [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as
> the name of a variable.

Included below is an example for using `is_callable()`:
<?php
//  How to check a variable to see if it can be called
//  as a function.

```
//
//  Simple variable containing a function
//

function someFunction() 
{
}

$functionVariable = 'someFunction';

var_dump(is_callable($functionVariable, false, $callable_name));  // bool(true)

echo $callable_name, "\n";  // someFunction

//
//  Array containing a method
//

class someClass {

  function someMethod() 
  {
  }

}

$anObject = new someClass();

$methodVariable = array($anObject, 'someMethod');

var_dump(is_callable($methodVariable, true, $callable_name));  //  bool(true)

echo $callable_name, "\n";  //  someClass::someMethod

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible through something called reflection.